# "snipe" command that shows last deleted message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, I'm trying to make a "snipe" command in discord.js that basically reveals the last deleted message on a channel.
My command works like this: once a message is deleted, my bot triggers this event.

```
client.on("messageDelete", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  var snipes = require("./snipe.json");
  snipes[`${message.channel.id}`] = [`${message}`, `${message.author.tag}`];

  var fs = require('fs');
  var fileName = './snipe.json';

  fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(snipes, null, 2), function(error) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log('oops')
    }
  });
});
```

Then it stores the message like this:

```
"Channel id": [
  "Message",
  "Author tag"
]
// of course not like this
```

And the thing is, I'm having problems when trying to make it specific for the channel id the message belongs to. My code looks like this at the moment:

```
var snipes = require("./snipe.json"); // file containing snipes
let chn = `${message.channel.id}`;
var snipechannel = snipes.chn; // to call an specific deleted message I guess

if (snipechannel[0] === "No snipes") {
  message.channel.send("What? There are no deleted messages atm");
} else {
  const embed = {
    "color": 5608903,
    "footer": {
      "text": `Sniped by: ${message.author.tag}`
    },
    "fields": [{
      "name": `${snipechannel[1]} said...`,
      "value": `${snipechannel[0]}`
    }]
  };
  await message.channel.send({
    embed
  });
  snipechannel[0] = "No snipes";

  var fileName = './snipe.json';
  var file = require(fileName);

  fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(file, null, 2), function(error) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log('oops');
    }
  });
}
```

The problem here is that I can't get any specific message depending on the channel id in the JSON file.
If there's something I haven't explained too well tell me in the comments

Comment: `snipes.chn` searches for an actual `chn` attribute on the `snipes` object, not the value of the variable `chn`. Could you try using `snipes[chn]` instead ?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much1

Comment: @tektiv Could you post it as an answer, so that the author can accept it and close the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from how you access the property.
Using `snipes.chn` as you do searches for an actual property named `chn`.

If you want to access the property named as the value of the variable `chn`, you need to use `snipes[chn]` instead :

```js
var snipes = require("./snipe.json");
let chn = `${message.channel.id}`;
var snipechannel = snipes[chn]; // change here
```